# merge pdfs with PDFTK and same Starting Filename

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to use pdftk to search a directory for similar file names and combine them.

I found a wonderful script written by Aacini and it works wonderful when used with the format NAME_KM_1, NAME_KM_2, NAME_KM_3, etc. It will combine all files with *KM* into a pdf.

In my scenario my file names all start with something like this Q1111_CONFIRM, Q1111_ORDER, Q2222_CONFIRM, Q2222_ORDER. How would I modify this one to combine the order/confirm matching the Qnumber? I tried a few different things with no success.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

rem Initialize (delete) "lastFile" and "fileList" variables
set "lastFile="
set "fileList="

rem Next line get the output of a "dir /B" command, that show file names 
*only*
rem "for /F" command execute the dir, get the output and divide each line in 
two "tokens" ("%%a" and "%%b")
rem with the first part before the "_" in "%%a" and the *rest* (including f 
urther "_") in "%%b"

for /F "tokens=1* delims=_" %%a in ('dir /B *_KM_*.*') do (

rem If the base file name changed...
if "%%a" neq "!lastFile!" (

  rem Process previous file list;
  rem this "if" is just to avoid process the empty list the first time
  if defined fileList (
     pdftk !fileList! output !lastFile!.pdf
  )

  rem Reinitialize the new list
  set "lastFile=%%a"
  set "fileList=%%a_%%b"

) else (

  rem Append this file to current list
  set "fileList=!fileList! %%a_%%b"

)

)

rem Process the last list
pdftk !fileList! output !lastFile!.pdf
```

Comment: Would anyone be able to help with this?

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

rem Initialize (delete) "lastFile" and "fileList" variables
set "lastFile="
set "fileList="

rem Next line get the output of a "dir /B" command, that show file names *only*
rem "for /F" command execute the dir, get the output and divide each line in two "tokens" ("%%a" and "%%b")
rem with the first part before the "_" in "%%a" and the *rest* (including further "_") in "%%b"

for /F "tokens=1* delims=_" %%a in ('dir /B ***.*') do (
  rem If the base file name changed...
  if "%%a" neq "!lastFile!" (
    rem Process previous file list;
    rem this "if" is just to avoid process the empty list the first time
    if defined fileList (
      pdftk !fileList! output !lastFile!.pdf
    )

    rem Reinitialize the new list
    set "lastFile=%%a"
    set "fileList=%%a_%%b"
  ) else (
    rem Append this file to current list
    set "fileList=!fileList! %%a_%%b"
  )
)

rem Process the last list
pdftk !fileList! output !lastFile!.pdf
```